# Oracle Contains search with Apostrope

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g and  I have a table called `test` with the columns `firstname` and `lastname`.

1. `firstname` column contains `D'Arch`
2. `Lastname` column contains `O'Neil`

and I have the index combining the `firstname` and `lastname` column and am using `CONTAINS (firstname, '%'|| 'D''A' ||'%') >0`

Oracle Query is

```
select * 
from test 
where CONTAINS (firstname, '%'|| 'D''Ar' ||'%') >0
```

But the result set is empty. Oracle  `Like` and `instr` keywords are  working fine but I don't want to change the existing implementation.

Any suggestion to this problem.

Comment: Check the definition of your lexer. the apostrope is probable defined as a [skipjoin](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cdatadic.htm#sthref535), but must be defined as *printjoin* to enable the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume those sample data - see below the CTAS statement to create them.

```
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
--------- --------
D'Arch    O'Neil   
DArch     ONeil    
D Arch    O Neil   
D.Arch    O.Neil
```

To preserve the apostrophe, you must define it as a [*printjoin*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cdatadic.htm#GUID-253EE2AA-F9C6-49E1-9EA4-4A05F803FF24__CHDBCEBH) character. Otherwise it will be removed in the tokenising process (compare with the dot in the last line).

```
BEGIN
  ctxsys.ctx_ddl.create_preference('lex', 'BASIC_LEXER');
  ctxsys.ctx_ddl.set_attribute('lex', 'printjoins', '''');  
END;
/
---
BEGIN
  ctxsys.ctx_ddl.create_preference('pref', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('pref', 'columns', 'firstname, lastname');
END;
/

create index idx_test on test(firstname)
indextype is CTXSYS.CONTEXT
parameters ('datastore  pref LEXER  lex')
;
```

The best way to see the result tokes after the index creation is to query the  `$I` table, which comtains all tokes:

```
select TOKEN_TEXT from DR$IDX_TEST$I;

TOKEN_TEXT                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------
ARCH                                                             
D'ARCH                                                           
DARCH                                                            
FIRSTNAME                                                        
LASTNAME                                                         
NEIL                                                             
O                                                                
O'NEIL                                                           
ONEIL
```

So as expected the dot disapears, but the apostrophe survived.

Now you can query and you get the expected result:

```
select * 
from test 
where CONTAINS (firstname, '%D''Ar%') >0;

FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
--------- --------
D'Arch    O'Neil
```

An of course, as you use [`MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cdatadic.htm#GUID-09F6DE00-B354-443E-9174-71CE88F5942E) you may query also the data from the column `lastname`.

```
select * 
from test 
where CONTAINS (firstname, '%O''Ne%') >0;

FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
--------- --------
D'Arch    O'Neil
```

Sample data

```
create table test as
select 'D''Arch' firstname, 'O''Neil' Lastname from dual union all
select 'DArch' firstname, 'ONeil' Lastname from dual union all
select 'D Arch' firstname, 'O Neil' Lastname from dual union all
select 'D.Arch' firstname, 'O.Neil' Lastname from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks but i already have mutlistore index on this firstname column . on running the new index it says"cannot create multiple domain indexes on a column list using same indextype"

Comment: After droping the exisitng index and recreating .. this worked fine.